# configure redirect rules in a apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-httpd, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I have a apache reverse proxy setting where I have to redirect all requests from abc.com to abc-test.com, the backend for this proxy is a AWS ALB. I have the below config which is not working:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /  https://internal-us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/ retry=0 connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
ProxyPassReverse /  https://internal-us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
  <Proxy https://internal-us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/*>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://abc-test$1 [L,R]
```

I have multiple other virtual hosts in the same apache config with different backends, surprisingly the above vhost is being redirected to a different backend. Only having a redirect rule in vhost replicates this behavior else things are fine.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but at least in the apache guides, both urls end with a slash `/`, which is missing in your `ProxyPassReverse` line.

Comment: Yes, but I have tried that but did not work, also similar config works on a different environment.